# Rails Model Callback Not Working (Creating new instance of a different class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

In my `circuit.rb` class I have the following

```
class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :create_service

  def create_service
    # create service record
    service = Service.new :service_type => 'Circuit', :child_id => self.id, :organisation_id => self.organisation_id
  end
```

I only want the callback to fire when the `circuit` is created, I've tried `before_validation` aswell, no errors in the log, in fact, there is no mention of the `services` table being touched, I've restarted the server aswell just as a precaution but not sure why the `service` instance isn't being saved.

For completeness:

```
class CircuitController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...
    if request.post?
      if @circuit
        # update
      else
        # attempt create
        @circuit = Circuit.new params[:circuit]
        if @circuit.save
          redirect_to :action => 'update', :id => @circuit.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, all columns in the table allow `NULL`, except the `id` column which is `AUTO_INCREMENT` anyway so there's nothing on the database side that would prevent a record being saved, similarly there is no validation in the model and the `circuit` is saved properly.

Comment: try `Service.create` instead of `Service.new`…

Comment: You should consider not creating a new resource inside your `update` method but in a `create` method.

Comment: Thanks j03w, yeah, completely missed that one, Pierre, yeah I prefer it that way too, this is a legacy code base and all the update/create part of the CRUD is done via an update action.

Comment: You can also refer to the information in [this post](http://brettu.com/ruby-ruby-tips-210-confirm-before_save-callback-on-create/) if you want to be certain that your callback is firing only on either create or update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback is probably firing properly. The problem is that you're setting up a new `Service`, but not actually saving it. When your controller redirects, the `Circuit` object is reloaded and loses the `Service` object.

You probably want to actually create the object:

```
service = Service.create :service_type => 'Circuit', :child_id => self.id, :organisation_id => self.organisation_id
```

Comment: .... ah, facepalm moment, can't believe I didn't see that. thanks for helping me out.